# Connect App with Server

Tags: java, android, sockets, server

I have created two Java programs, a server and a client which can communicate with each other, if they're executed on the same PC.

Server:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;    
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Server {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(30);


    ServerSocket server;

    try {

        server = new ServerSocket(5555);
        System.out.println("Server gestartet!");


        while(true){


            try {

                Socket client = server.accept();

                //Thread t = new Thread(new Handler(client));
                //t.start();

                executor.execute(new Handler(client));


            } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
} 
}
```

Handler (Server creates each time an instance when a new client joins):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Handler implements Runnable {

private Socket client;

public Handler(Socket client) {
    this.client = client;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try{
        //Streams
        OutputStream out = client.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(out);

        InputStream in = client.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        // ------------------------------

        String s = null;

        while((s = reader.readLine()) != null){

            writer.write(s + "\n");
            writer.flush();
            System.out.println("Empfangen vom Client: " + s);

        }

        writer.close();
        reader.close();
        client.close();

    }catch(Exception e){}
}
}
```

Client:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Socket client = new Socket("localhost", 5555);
        System.out.println("Client gestartet!");

        //Streams
        OutputStream out = client.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(out);

        InputStream in = client.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        // ------------------------------

        writer.write("Hallo Server!\n");
        writer.flush();


        String s = null;

        while((s = reader.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println("Empfangen vom Server: " + s);
        }

        reader.close();
        writer.close();

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

My question now is: 
How can make a server on my computer which can be accessed via Internet? My first thougt was to change something in the constructor of the client socket

```
Socket client = new Socket("localhost", 5555);
```

"localhost" probably means that the server runs on the same PC as the client.

My goal would be to have an app on my smartphone which connects via Internet to my server which runs on my PC. It should send back my message I entered.

Comment: If you want your application accessible on the Internet, it really depends on your OS and Network setup how this is made possible. The question is better suited for ServerFault or SuperUsers forums as in the end it is not so much about the code, but rather setting up a server.

Comment: For the client you should use the internet ip address of your router. Find out with calling whatismyip.com from your pc. Then configure your router so it forwards incoming requests on port 5555 to the LAN ip of your pc.

Comment: Please tell me how to do this on a netgear router.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get your public IP address using http://whatismyip.com
2. Change the client code to `Socket client = new Socket("<replace_with_your_public_ip>", 5555);`
3. Make sure the client is allowed to open outgoing connections to port 5555 (this is usually the case if connected in Wifi, but not if you are using 3G/4G)
4. Configure the router to which your server is connected, so that it redirects incoming connections from the Internet on port 5555 to the IP of your server on the LAN (still on port 5555). This kind of settings usually can be found in a section called "NAT", in the router admin console (usually accessible via http://192.168.0.1 or http://192.168.1.1 depending on the router model).

Comment: Could you please explain step 3 and 4 more accurate because i don't understand them.